# How to apply the same queue attribute setting (TTL) to all AWS SQS queues?

Tags: masstransit

I am trying to set the same TTL to all of the AWS SQS queues in our system.

I have found the code that can do that for error and DLQ queues:

```
cfg.SendTopology.ConfigureErrorSettings = settings => settings.QueueAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.MessageRetentionPeriod, 1209600);
cfg.SendTopology.ConfigureDeadLetterSettings = settings => settings.QueueAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.MessageRetentionPeriod, 1209600);
```

but I couldnt find thie same for normal queues.
I tried this, but it doesnt work:

```
cfg.QueueAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.MessageRetentionPeriod, 1209600);
```

Here is my full MassTransit setup:

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddAmazonSqsMessageScheduler();
    x.AddConsumers(assembliesWithConsumers.ToArray());
    x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UseAmazonSqsMessageScheduler();

        cfg.Host("aws", h =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mtSettings.AccessKey))
            {
                h.AccessKey(mtSettings.AccessKey);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mtSettings.SecretKey))
            {
                h.SecretKey(mtSettings.SecretKey);
            }

            h.Scope($"{mtSettings.Prefix}-{mtSettings.Environment}", true);
            var sqsConfig = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mtSettings.SqsServiceUrl)
                ? new AmazonSQSConfig() { ServiceURL = mtSettings.SqsServiceUrl }
                : new AmazonSQSConfig()
                    { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(mtSettings.Region) };

            h.Config(sqsConfig);

            var snsConfig = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mtSettings.SnsServiceUrl)
                ? new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceConfig()
                    { ServiceURL = mtSettings.SnsServiceUrl }
                : new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceConfig()
                    { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(mtSettings.Region) };

            h.Config(snsConfig);
        });

        cfg.QueueAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.MessageRetentionPeriod, 1209600);
        cfg.SendTopology.ConfigureErrorSettings = settings => settings.QueueAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.MessageRetentionPeriod, 1209600);
        cfg.SendTopology.ConfigureDeadLetterSettings = settings => settings.QueueAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.MessageRetentionPeriod, 1209600);

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context, new BusEnvironmentNameFormatter(mtSettings.Environment));
    });
});
```

I tested the code above (by deleting and recreating the queues), and I can see that error queue is created correctly with updated TTL, however normal queue doesnt have that setting updated.

How can I set the same queue attribute (TTL) to all of the SQS queues in a single place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a delegate called when a receive endpoint is configured by `ConfigureEndpoints`, and set the queue attribute in that callback.

> Note that error/dead-letter queues automatically copy the queue attributes of the queue

The relevant code changes are shown below.

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddAmazonSqsMessageScheduler();
    x.AddConsumers(assembliesWithConsumers.ToArray());

    x.AddConfigureEndpointsCallback((name, cfg) =>
    {
        if(cfg is IAmazonSqsReceiveEndpointConfigurator configurator)
        {
            configurator.QueueAttributes.Add(QueueAttributeName.MessageRetentionPeriod, 1209600);
        }
    });

    x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.UseAmazonSqsMessageScheduler();

        cfg.Host("aws", h =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mtSettings.AccessKey))
            {
                h.AccessKey(mtSettings.AccessKey);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mtSettings.SecretKey))
            {
                h.SecretKey(mtSettings.SecretKey);
            }

            h.Scope($"{mtSettings.Prefix}-{mtSettings.Environment}", true);
            var sqsConfig = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mtSettings.SqsServiceUrl)
                ? new AmazonSQSConfig() { ServiceURL = mtSettings.SqsServiceUrl }
                : new AmazonSQSConfig()
                    { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(mtSettings.Region) };

            h.Config(sqsConfig);

            var snsConfig = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mtSettings.SnsServiceUrl)
                ? new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceConfig()
                    { ServiceURL = mtSettings.SnsServiceUrl }
                : new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceConfig()
                    { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(mtSettings.Region) };

            h.Config(snsConfig);
        });

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context, new BusEnvironmentNameFormatter(mtSettings.Environment));
    });
});
```

Comment: This is great, thank you very much!

Comment: I have tested the code above, and now it only creates TTL for normal queues, error/dead-letter queues do not automatically copy the queue attributes. I had to add back the the original `ConfigureErrorSettings` and `ConfigureDeadLetterSettings` code and finally all the queues have the max TTL setting (after deleting and recreating them of course)

Comment: Are you on an old version of MassTransit? The [code](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/a42a35e936d9601466b96cc1287a749e053322f0/src/Transports/MassTransit.AmazonSqsTransport/Topology/Settings/QueueErrorSettings.cs#L16) clearly copies the attributes of the queue to the error/dead-letter queues.

Comment: Interesting. I have updated to the latest available 7.2.2 to even be able to compile above code, as my previous 7.1.5 version didnt even have `AddConfigureEndpointsCallback` available.
I also made sure to clean and rebuild with the new version, however it can be that some other configuration somewhere on my machine has affected this (for example we have `ConsumerDefinition` for the tested queue, although I cant see how it could affect it). 
It would be great to see what other people's experience is.